# How can I replace the popup window with an other page in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I created an extension what is working in Firefox.
I changed it for Google Chrome, but it is not working.
When I click on the extension's icon then popup shown with two menu option.
But when I click on any of these links nothing happened. If I press right click on any of these links and choose open in new tab then this html file shown in a new tab. If I click on links in this new tab php file will be open and works, so I think window.location.replace does not work in crome extension.

Do anybody have any idea, how can I resolve this problem?

**manifest.json**

```
{
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": {
  "48": "images/startlapom-48.png",
  "96": "images/startlapom-96.png"
},
"browser_style": true,
"default_title": "Startlapom",
"default_popup": "managestartlapom.html"
},
"description": "Oldal hozzáadása, levétele a Startlapom oldalam(ra/ról)",
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Startlapom",
"permissions": ["tabs"],
"version": "1.0"
}
```

**managestartlapom.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Startlapom</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="managestartlapom.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://startlapom.eu/startlapom.css" type="text/css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>

  <body class="addon-body">
    <div id="startlapom-addon">
      <div class="panel">
        <a class="addon-link" href="#" id="startlapom-add">Oldal hozzáadása a Startlapomhoz</a><br />

        <div class="panel-section-separator"></div>

        <a class="addon-link" href="#" id="startlapom-remove">Oldal levétele a Startlapomról</a><br />
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="managestartlapom.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**managestartlapom.js**

```
document.getElementById('startlapom-add').onclick = function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    window.location.replace('https://startlapom.eu/addon.php?url='+encodeURIComponent(tabs[0].url)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(tabs[0].title)+'&reason=ADD');
      });
    }

document.getElementById('startlapom-remove').onclick = function() {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    window.location.replace('https://startlapom.eu/addon.php?url='+encodeURIComponent(tabs[0].url)+'&title='+encodeURIComponent(tabs[0].title)+'&reason=REM');
      });
    }
```

Comment: Looks like Chrome forbids navigating the popup to a non-extension URL. I think you'll have to add an iframe (sized to the entire popup dimensions) and assign its src property.

Comment: To clarify (I'm guessing the answer is correct): are you trying to change the active tab's URL, or are you trying to replace the contents of the popup itself (then why are you querying for tabs?)

Comment: I would like to replace content of popup window, tabs query is needed for me because I would like to post the current tab url and title to php page as you can see in managestartlapom.js.

Answer (score 1):

If you write in your `managestartlapom.js` file:

```
....
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  alert(window.location);
  .......
```

}

you will see that your `window.location` is equal to

```
chrome-extension://ext_id_here/managestartlapom.html#
```

and I think it is not the `window.location` you would like to replace. (it is the window of your popup menu). 
If you want to replace `window.location` of your active tab page, you should use [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) in your `chrome.tabs.query` callback.

Comment: Or, simpler, `chrome.tabs.update` to change the URL.

Comment: Yes I know, this is the popup window, but I would like to show the php page in this popup window, not in the new tab.